# how to call a javascript function in the top frame?

Tags: javascript, frames

This seems really simple, but how do I call a javascript function that's defined in the top-level html, from a child frame?

```
top html doc
 - 1st level frame
    - 2nd level frame
```

my top html doc has a function called testFn(). In the 2nd level frame I have a button with `onclick="top.testFn();"` but this doesn't call the testFn(). In Firebug if I use a watch to execute `top.testFn();` it says TypeError: testFn() is not a function.

Should this all just work - in which case it's a problem with my documents, or is there some other way to call functions in the top-level window?

Comment: Are all documents involved on the same domain and protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks right. If it says `testFn() is not a function` then perhaps it isn't. Have you tried setting `onload="testFn();"` in the `<BODY>` of your top frame to make sure that works?

There could be some javascript error which leads to the code creating your `testFn` function not being successfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling it like this:

> onclick="parent.parent.testFn();"

I am assuming you have the 2nd frame inside the 1st frame.

Comment: Thanks - turns out it was just a mistake elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is exactly how you do it.

The trick is not having a syntax error elsewhere in the javascript on that top-level html page :-)